# Dynamic height for tableview cell based on Stackview's height

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uistackview

**Tableview cell not expanding based on the Stackview's height**. The cell has container view for holding stack view, I'll add subviews programmatically to Stackview on `cellForRowAt:`. If no views added to the StackView, Its height should be 0. Otherwise, it should be some based on subview's height. My layout is below.

[image]

Xib file is below. It shows the Stackview's height as zero in this layout.

[image]

The problem is When I am adding Imageview to Stackview during `cellForRowAt`:, It gets adding but cell's height not expanding.

**Note:**

It's horizontal stack view

Comment: If its in cellForRow, maybe call layoutIfNeeded is better

Comment: Make sure content in Stackview having bottom and top constraint to Stackview....

Comment: @Tj3n Tried but not working.

Comment: @ManishM.Mahajan Wow. It's working. I tried. Please post your comment as answer. I'll mark it accepted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Make sure content in Stackview having bottom and top constraint to
>   Stackview....

When you assign top and bottom constraint for content in Stackview, Stackview height automatically increases as its content size..

And no need to extra suggestion that tableview cell height should be automatic set.. means look below code.....

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Comment: Just elaborate your answer with example otherwise SO' people will mark as deleted.

Comment: Also, your explanation will help the future visitors.